# correlation between two functions of a random variable

Tags: random-variables, correlation

Suppose random variable $X$ has distribution depending on $\theta \in S$, and for some function $g(X)$ is uncorrelated with any function of $X$ at some $\theta_0 \in S$, i.e., $E_{\theta_0} (g(X)h(X)) = E_{\theta_0}(g(X))E_{\theta_0}(h(X))$, for any function $h$. Can we conclude that $E_{\theta} (g(X)h(X)) = E_\theta (g(X)) E_\theta(h(X))$ holds for all $\theta \in S$ ?

Comment: How can $g(X)$ be uncorrelated with any function of $X$ unless $g(X)$ ( or $X$ itself) is constant?

Comment: More generally, if (X,Y) has joint distribution depending on $\theta \in S$, and if $E_{\theta_0} (Yh(X)) = E_{\theta_0}(Y)E_{\theta_0}(h(X))$, for any function $h$. Can we conclude that $E_{\theta} (Yh(X)) = E_\theta (Y) E_\theta(h(X))$ holds for all $\theta \in S$ ?

Comment: And what if $X$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$ ?

Comment: Say X and Y are bivariate normal N(0,1)'s and $\theta$ is the correlation parameter. Then $E_{\theta_0}(Yh(X)) = E_{\theta_0}(Y)E_{\theta_0}(h(X))$ when the correlation is 0 (since they're independent). but when the correlation is nonzero the relationship won't hold.

Comment: I think in the case where it's sufficient it might hold. Sufficiency implies the conditional distribution of y given x has no dependence on theta. So if they are independent for one value of theta, that would imply the conditional distribution of y given x doesn't depend on x and thus x and y are independent. But since the cond distribution doesn't depend on theta, this must be true for all theta.

Comment: How x and y are independent? I have came up with an solution: $E_{\theta_0}(Yh(X)) = E_{\theta_0}(Y)E_{\theta_0}(h(X))$ implies $E_{\theta_0}(Y|X) = E_{\theta_0}(Y)$, sufficiency implies $E_{\theta_0}(Y|X) = E_{\theta}(Y|X)$, hence $E_{\theta}(Y|X) = E_{\theta_0}(Y)$, a constant. Now, $E_{\theta}(YT(X)) = E_{\theta}(E_{\theta}(Y|X)T(X)) = E_{\theta_0}(Y)E_{\theta}(T(X))=E_{\theta}(Y)E_{\theta}(T(X)) $, last equality is due to $E_{\theta}(Y)=E_{\theta}{E_{\theta}(Y|X)} = E_{\theta_0}(Y)$.

Comment: $T(X)$ should be $h(X)$ above